# How do I install a chromebook keyboard on ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, chromebook

I downloaded ubuntu to my Lenovo N22 chromebook and the keyboard isn't functioning. The TouchPad works fine but not the keyboard. What drivers do I need?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu did you download? 16.04 or 16.10? I'm not sure if kernel 4.8 from 16.10 makes the keyboard work, I only use Gallium OS and its 4.7 kernel on my N22.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0-62 will work.  Earlier 4.0 kernels had trouble with skylake.  Plug in a USB keyboard and upgrade until you are current.